Нужны ли запятые в данных предложениях с союзами?
1. Он вышел в ночь стоило только ударам в дверь прекратиться.
2. Мы ещё не выяснили точно ли можем помочь.

Правильно:

Он вышел в ночь, стоило только ударам в дверь прекратиться.

Мы ещё не выяснили, точно ли можем помочь.


Пояснение

В предложении две предикативные основы, сравнить:

Он вышел в ночь, как только удары в дверь прекратились.
Это СПП со значением времени,  фразеологизированное предложение.
В этом случае надо указывать средства связи. Это союзные слова стоило только  и инфинитивная форма глагола.
Теория: Предложения с союзным соединением стоит — чтобы (как, и)
 § 3068. В отличие от построений типа стоит (стоило) — 
 чтобы, где союз чтобы обязателен, союзы как и и могут 
 опускаться.  Захочет чего-нибудь Илья Ильич, ему стоит 
 только мигнуть — уж трое-четверо слуг кидаются исполнять 
 его желание (Гонч.); Стоит ему слово сказать, артель 
 встанет как один человек (М.Печ.); Но стоило ему показаться 
 на сцене —  он побеждал (К. Коровин); 


Мы ещё не выяснили, точно ли можем помочь.

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, в роли союза вопросительная частица ЛИ.
